# How to trigger python transitions with async twisted deferred events

Tags: python, transition

I am using python transitions for my FSM, its good with sequential events and recently added timeout features. My code is totally asyc based on txdbus (Twisted based dbus event) where I use defer for any asynchronous event in system or hardware and code is running in a reactor loop.

Now if I start transitions states and based on conditions it calls a functions that give TRUE/False in future time(initially return a deferred, but actually runs a call which is asynchronous like wait for file download, and returns with success/failure of file download in future)

In this case how to maintain the statemachine and transition to next state only when the asyc function from the reactor loop  comes back.
(I tried setting state after the callback of my function, but it doesnt work)

Anyone has worked with FSM transitions, and twisted (Or I am making things complicated :) )

Comment: Please show us your related code!

Comment: I have a similar issue. Did you find a solution?